# How can I make a div show using jQuery if a GET variable exists in the url?

Tags: jquery, forms, get

I have two separate forms on the index.php page:

```
<form action="search_results.php" method="get" id="search_housing_area">
  <input type="text" name="rent_housing" />
  <inout type="submit" name="search_housing" value="" />
</form>

<form action="search_results.php" method="get" id="search_rooms_area">
  <input type="text" name="rent_rooms" />
  <inout type="submit" name="search_rooms" value="" />
</form>
```

When I submit either of those forms the url appears as:

> http://www.domain.com/search_results.php?rent_housing=1234&search_housing=

OR

> http://www.domain.com/search_results.php?rent_rooms=1234&search_rooms=

On the search_results.php page, I have two divs, #housing_results and #rooms_results. They are both hidden by default. If the GET variable 'search_housing' exists, I would like to show div#housing_results and if the the GET variable 'search_rooms' exists, I would like to show div#rooms_results.

How can I make a specific div show using jQuery if a specific GET variable exists in the url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
 $disp_div=0;
if(isset($_GET['search_housing']))
{
   $disp_div=1;
}
else if(isset($_GET['search_rooms']))
{
  $disp_div=2;
}
?>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var show=<?php echo $disp_div; ?>;

 if(show==1)
 {
   $('#div_search_housing').show();
 }
else if(show==2)
 {
   $('#div_search_rooms').show();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.location` and search the `query string`.

```
var winLoc = window.location.search;
//will output ?rent_rooms=1234&search_rooms=
```

Now we'll remove the ?, split the strings on the `&` symbol, and make it an array

```
winLoc = winLoc.replace('?', '').split('&');

var  ourStr = winLoc[1].replace('=', '');

switch(ourStr){
  case 'search_rooms':
    $('.switch').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    break;
  case 'search_housing':
    $('.switch').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
    break;       
}
```

**[Here is a working jsFiddle with a predefined string, for examples sake](http://jsfiddle.net/sVJSA/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure JS solution. There are also ways to do this using PHP, as mentioned in the other answers.

```
function stuff()
{
    var queryPairs = window.location.href.split('?').pop().split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < queryPairs.length; i++)
    {
        var pair = queryPairs[i].split('=');
        if (pair[0] == 'search_housing')
        {
            $('#rooms_results').hide();
            $('#housing_results').show();
            return;
        }
        if (pair[0] == 'search_rooms')
        {
            $('#housing_results').hide();
            $('#rooms_results').show();
            return;
        }
     }
     // None of the two options exist in the query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure JS:

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    if(results == null)
    return "";
    else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

So in your case it should be like this:

```
if (getParameterByName('search_housing').length > 0) { ... } 
if (getParameterByName('search_rooms').length > 0)  { ... }
```